# Update to macOS Catalina has ruined the quality of FaceTime HD Camera

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, facetime, webcam

An update to macOS Catalina has made the quality of the built-in webcam that awful that will feel guilty during zoom session, because other participants' eyes could bleed: overall quality 20x times worse than it was in Mavericks, but the main concern is a ghosting problem. When I close my eyes and then open them - I can see on the web camera application the moment when my eyes are closed. When I move my head – all my face is very blurred.

My device: MBP late 2013, 15"

I don't want to install any other versions of macOS since they give other problems and I got used to Catalina.

Is there any way how to fix it without changing the macOS version? Maybe it's possible to install drivers from the older version? The situation is much better on Big Sur, but it gives other bugs, so I don't really want to use it..

Comment: Did this happen upgrading from Mavericks (not Mojave?) to Catalina, or from one version of Catalina to another? I've not heard of any similar complaints. So you're saying that it seems 'slow'? Is it possible that it could just be due to a busy CPU, or full RAM (or even a full disk?) Check Activity Monitor to see what's going on.

Comment: @benwiggy, thank you for your reply. I got Catalina upgrading my system from Sierra to Catalina. Everything is okay is resources loading, mac isn't slow and works well.

Comment: Is this only in Zoom? What about Photobooth? It may be an internet connection issue. And make sure your version of Zoom is the latest for Catalina.

Comment: No, it happens in all programs.

Comment: You've tested it on Big Sur? What are these "other bugs"? Sometimes, you have to choose which bugs you want.

Comment: Yes, I see. I've tried a few versions of macOS, and all of them have noticeably worse webcam quality than in Mavericks, but none of them has that awful problem as in Catalina (as I said — ghosting is unbearable). By other bugs I mean in the latest version of BIg Sur — freezes of my sound (or something of this kind) when using Zoom (other participant complain about it); in the earlier version of Big Sur — sometimes (especially while watching youtube in full screen) CPU load goes to 100% the temperature is really hight and the fans becomes really lound).

Comment: TBH, I'm  not convinced that these are universal complaints, and  it's more likely that this is a local issue on your machine. Have you tested the behaviour in Safe Boot mode, or in a brand nuew user account?